# Expression regarding a periodic task

Tags: phrase-requests, time, recurring-events

So, if I have to do a certain task during a whole week but with a 3-week gap.
For instance, in a 3-week period I will have to do that task for 1 week, in a 6-week period for 2 weeks, not in a row, of course, and so on.

> 1. One work week for each 3-weeks.
> 2. Once in every 3-weeks.
> 3. ...

Which is the best way to express this work schedule rotation?

Comment: Others have answered, but side note: Don't hyphenate an adjective with a noun in general. Just write "for each 3 weeks". You only hyphenate when the adjective and noun are being used as a compound adjective to modify some other noun. Like, "for each 3-week period". Here "3-week" is acting as an adjective. And it's conventional to spell out numbers less than twenty or so, so better still is "for each three weeks" or "for each three-week period".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply say *one week out of three*, as in

> We work *one week out of three*.

or

> You will work *one week out of three*.

Comment: That's it, yhank yoou a lot :D

Answer (score 3):

- One work week in every three-week period.
- One work week per three weeks.

Don’t hyphenate as a noun phase, only when making a compound adjective.  And don’t use numerals; use words.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the schedule is linear/predictable, I'd refer to it as, "I work every third week"

Comment: Every third week you could be working for a day, not necessarily a week.